# TinyMCE Read Only - Links not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce, tinymce-4

I put the TinyMCE content inside a modal on read only mode so the user can see the content but cannot change it. The content is rendering OK but my links are not working. Does not trigger any link.

```
tinyMCE.init({
            selector: '#notificacao-text',
            readonly : 1,
            toolbar: false,
            menubar: false,
            statusbar: false,
            width: 'auto',
            height: 300,
            extended_valid_elements: 'a[href|target=_parent]',
            content_css : '/styles/tinymce.css'
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When links are shown in TinyMCE they are not "active" - clicking on the links won't trigger the browser to open the link.

In TinyMCE 4.5.2+ right clicking on a link shows an Open Link option which you can use to open the link in a separate tab/window.